# array index changing into string [name] not number

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have form (display.php) that will get multiple selected option from user. Then this selected option will be formatted to another page (page.php). The problem occur when I try to display those multiple selected option. The array index are changing into string [name]!

**Array ( [0] => 3204120006 [1] => 3204120011 [2] => 3204120010 [3] => 3204120009 ) 
Array ( [name] => BIRU ) Array ( [name] => BOJONG ) Array ( [name] => MAJAKERTA ) Array ( [name] => MAJALAYA )**

Here the code of above display.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["desas"])) {
$ddes=$_POST["desas"];
print_r ($ddes);
foreach ( $ddes as $iddesa ) {
$namadesa=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM villages WHERE id='$iddesa' ");
if ($namadesa) {
    $datadesa = mysql_fetch_assoc($namadesa);
    print_r($datadesa);
}
} else 
  $datadesa="";
}

?>
```

My question is how to change ([name]=>BIRU),([name]=>BOJONG) into index ([0]=>BIRU),([1]=>BOJONG) etc on those array? or something missing in mysql fetch?

Comment: How about, stop using mysql_* functions, for starters? They've been deprecated for years and were removed from PHP 7 over a year ago.

Comment: @Sherif Then I would add the OP should give more details about this `app.php` and indent his code correctly

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Answer (score -2):

you can use `array_values`. reference: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

```
$datadesa = array_values(array_values);
```

Comment: Why bother using `mysql_fetch_assoc` then if you're just going to throw away the array and rebuild it? It would make more sense to use `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)`, but then again, I have no idea why we're even using an extension that's no longer supported in PHP.

Comment: thanks @Sherif .. and you have any ideas how to deal with my problem? the data of villages, districts, regencies and provinces are store in databases..